# Finding the area of the triangle using array with given vertices for the user to prompt

Tags: c

I am trying to get this problem done, but for some reason it does not read my values and the area in the ouput. When I run it, gives me zeros.
I will appreciate any help or suggestions.

This is the output:

```
Please enter value of your three vertex x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3:
1
2
5
6
8
9
with given vertices 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, and 0.00, the area is 0.00
--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is what I have done so far on the code.

Thanks!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){

float arr[6];
int i;
float side1, side2, side3, sidet, area, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;

x1=arr[0];
y1=arr[1];
x2=arr[2];
y2=arr[3];
x3=arr[4];
y3=arr[5];

printf("Please enter value of your three vertex x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3: \n");
for(i=0; i<6; i++){
scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
}

//calculation
side1=pow(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)), 0.5);

side2=pow(((x3-x2)*(x3-x2)+(y3-y2)*(y3-y2)), 0.5);

side3=pow(((x3-x1)*(x3-x1)+(y3-y1)*(y3-y1)), 0.5);

//calculations

sidet=(side1+side2+side3)*0.5;

area=pow((sidet*(sidet-side1)*(sidet-side2)*(sidet-side3)), 0.5);

printf("with given vertices %0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f, and %0.2f, the area is %0.2f",x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,area);



return 0;
}
```

Comment: All these `x`s and `y`s take the value of `arr[i]` before it was set by `scanf()`. If you move this block after the `scanf()` loop, you'd get it working!

Comment: Validate all user input by **checking the return** of `scanf`. Rather hard to make a triangle if all points lie on a line... The line equation is `y = x + 1` **all three points lie on a line** and cannot form a triangle... (your zero area is thus correct `:)`

Comment: Thanks so much!! It worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the complete working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(){

    float arr[6];
    int i;
    float side1, side2, side3, sidet, area, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;

    printf("Please enter value of your three vertex x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3: \n");
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
            scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
    }

    x1=arr[0];
    y1=arr[1];
    x2=arr[2];
    y2=arr[3];
    x3=arr[4];
    y3=arr[5];


    //calculation
    side1=pow(((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)), 0.5);

    side2=pow(((x3-x2)*(x3-x2)+(y3-y2)*(y3-y2)), 0.5);

    side3=pow(((x3-x1)*(x3-x1)+(y3-y1)*(y3-y1)), 0.5);

    //calculations

    sidet=(side1+side2+side3)*0.5;

    area=pow((sidet*(sidet-side1)*(sidet-side2)*(sidet-side3)), 0.5);
    printf("with given vertices %0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f, %0.2f, and %0.2f, the area is %0.2f",x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,area);



    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`x1=arr[0];` does not establish a relationship.  It does the assignment at that point, not based on some later value of `arr[0]`.

Move the following earlier in code:

```
printf("Please enter value of your three vertex x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3: \n");
for(i=0; i<6; i++) {
  scanf("%f", &arr[i]);
}
```

Then assign

```
x1=arr[0];
y1=arr[1];
x2=arr[2];
y2=arr[3];
x3=arr[4];
y3=arr[5];
```